# Need help to validate if my understanding is correct regarding random forest and feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection

I'm currently doing binary classification task with about 40 features. The main goal of this task is finding important features. I built few tree based and binary classification models and one of my colleagues raised concern saying the data preparation might have impacted the final f1 score to be too high.

Please kindly note that this is just an example to describe my dataset.

[image]

His argument is that because

1. email values are significantly larger than other features for all data points and
2. email value is never null for every single data point
   -> hence, feature importance result might be biased.

I'm trying to understand if this argument is valid point because in my opinion the both of them should not be an issue especially model like random forest.

so my question is that

1. Is his argument valid in this case?
2. I even normalized the values(although I think this is not necessary) and test it but the result was the same. Is this the right practice?

I'm pretty new in this role and wanted to make sure I'm not making any mistake. Thank you for your help!